# Слишком большой CTR в AdMob в одной стране

Tags: android, mobile-development, admob, монетизация

**Дано:**

AdMob показывает такие данные по США:

1. **сегодня** - запросы 10, клики 1, CTR 10,00%, доход на тысячу запросов/показов 48,92$.
2. **вчера** - запросы 35, клики 3, CTR 8,57%, доход на тысячу запросов/показов 19,45$.
3. **этот месяц** - запросы 1178, клики 9, CTR 0,77%, доход на тысячу запросов/показов 2,37$.

**Проблема:**

Где-то когда-то читал, что могут забанить аккаунты гугл-плея и AdMob при CTR>8%, объясняя это накруткой кликов.

Связаться с AdMob сложно - они пишут, что из-за праздников могут долго отвечать или вообще не ответить, если у них этот вопрос на их ресурсах разрешён уже. Искать что-то на их ресурсах - страдание.

**Вопрос:**

Таки могут забанить при таких показателях или нет, т.к. смотрят они только на месячные показатели?

Comment: Там банится обычно автоматически роботами)

Comment: @Suvitruf, это не меняет сути вопроса)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я поэтому это лишь как комментарий и написал )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по тому, что за 3 месяца, при периодических повторах сей ситуации меня так и не забанили и гугл даже продолжает гроши слать, всё это либо нормально, либо незаметно.

Comment: @Deadkenny, нифига себе падение! Сочувствую( А это у вас полноэкраный баннер был, да? У меня-то просто смарт-баннер внизу экрана)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ага полноэкранный. 1 раз в 2 часа показывается. Маленькие банеры слишком назойливы мне кажется)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у меня тоже можно убрать рекламу, а приложение новостное, клиент одного популярного сайта у которого много пользователей:) И обычно сессия пользователя состовляет около 5-10 минут, поэтому по сути реклама показывается 1 раз за запуск приложения. Нормально в общем то:)

Comment: @Deadkenny, угу... Вот допишу новую версию, буду пробовать полноэкранки и видео. И таки скоплю себе на остров) А ссылочку уместно спросить? Я б идей потырил бы)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, вот http://goo.gl/BmSZPM

Comment: @Deadkenny, благодарю, судя по скринам - симпатично) Ждите баг репортов от меня)))

Comment: @Deadkenny, адЪово напрягает нужда удалять комменты, чтоб новый написать... Вот мой баг репорт, как обещал: 

1. В диалогах "История изменений" и "О приложении" текст не сскролится по инерции.

2. В ночной теме (мои юзеры тоже жаловались когда я так делал) режет глаз белый текст на чёрном. Мне (ИМХО) нравится больше серый на чёрном.

3. В "Хранилище" при нажатии на загрузку я растерялся - не информативно звучит "Вы уверены?". Я б написал: "Начать загрузку постов?".

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо за репорт:) Скоро будет обновления до material design, там поправлю. Если что, пишите на почту (она есть на странице приложения) :)